# Conjunctive normal form of Game Of life

Tags: conways-game-of-life, conjunctive-normal-form

I want to use minisat to solve a 7 * 7 size game of life, to get the stable generations.

Here I simplify the rule of live and death: 
[Von Neumann de rayon 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLzdO.png)
The cell who has south, east and north neighbors alive will be alive.
(xin : north neighbor; xie : east neighbors; xis : south neighbors)
[My formule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NASkq.png)
But I don't know to to change this to CNF(Conjunctive normal form)

Can someone help me? T

Comment: Some theorem provers have the ability to convert a first-order logic problem to CNF. Can you use one of them to do the conversion for you?

Answer (score 0):

The way I learned CNF, the "dead" formula is a single disjunctive term:

~xin V ~xie V ~xis

... which is simply the application of DeMorgan's theorem to the "live" case, which is already in CNF.

Remember, any expression whose operators are all disjuctions or all conjunctions, is already in **both** CNF and DNF.